# Assigning Parent ID based on the level hierarchy

Tags: python-3.x

| ID | Level |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Level 1 |
| 2 | Level 2 |
| 3 | Level 2 |
| 4 | Level 3 |
| 5 | Level 2 |
| 6 | Level 3 |

In the above table, ID 1 is the parent of IDs 2, 3 and 5.
ID 3 is the parent of ID 4.

I need to have this output in this format:

| ID | Level | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Level 1 | None |
| 2 | Level 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Level 2 | 1 |
| 4 | Level 3 | 3 |
| 5 | Level 2 | 1 |
| 6 | Level 3 | 5 |

I tried traversing down but then we also need to go up at each row to check if it is a sibling or a parent. The parent could be in any of the rows above it. For example, ID 5 has a parent all the way in the first row and not necessarily in the immediate preceding row. That is where I exactly fail.

Answer (score 0):

We'll create a new column called 'Parent' to store the parent information. The idea is to iterate over the rows, and for each row, check if there is a previous row with a higher level. If found, set that as the parent.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        'Level': ['Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 2', 'Level 3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Parent'] = None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    parent_index = None
    
    for i in range(index - 1, -1, -1):
        if df['Level'].iloc[i] < row['Level']:
            parent_index = i
            break
    
    if parent_index is not None:
        df.at[index, 'Parent'] = df.at[parent_index, 'ID']

df['Parent'] = df['Parent'].astype('Int64')

print(df)
```